# how to display the value of lable using tag in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have auto generated some Labels and now I need to overwrite the value in the label by getting the value of other label using its tag in xcode.

This is my `onclick` code:

```
- (IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender 
{

    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    NSLog(@"title ~~~~~~~~~~~ %@",title);
    for(i=0;i<vCount;i++) {
        pStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[pStrName characterAtIndex:i]];
        [pLblMyLable1 setTag:j+1];  
        iTag = [pLblMyLable1 tag];
        NSLog(@"ssssstttttrrrrriinnnngggg on click %@", pStr);
        if([title isEqualToString:pStr]){
            //pStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[pStrName characterAtIndex:i]];
            NSLog(@"came into if");
            pLblMyLable1.text = pStr;
        //pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:iTag];
        //  pStr = [pLblMyLable1.text:iTag];
            /*pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
            pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
            pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:3];
            pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:4];
            pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:5];
            pLblMyLable1 = [self.view viewWithTag:6];*/
}
```

Comment: where have you created the labels..?? also where have you added those in the view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the thing i did since i used a single label.... now works fine, intrestingly works good

```
NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
for(i=0;i<vCount;i++) {
    for (NSString* key in Name){
        UILabel *Select = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:[key intValue]];
        if ([title isEqualToString:Select.text]) { 
        Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[pStrName characterAtIndex:i]];
```

}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate through all the subviews grabbing only the UILabels. This can be done like this:

```
for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews){
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        NSLog(@"%d", [(UILabel*)subview tag]);
    }
}
```

This should get you going in the right direction.

Edit
In response to comment:
You can try this to see if it gets rid of error.

```
for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            NSLog(@"%d", [subview tag]);
        }
}
```

Comment: i got an subview undeclared error... what was that.... i m sorry i m new to xcode